# Extracting strings from list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've written some code that retrieves a piece of information from a google search but it returns the data to me in a list.  I need each item in the list stored in a separate variable. If you look at the output below, what I need is for each one of those pieces inside of the single quotes to be stored in its own variable. Can anyone help?

The code is included below:

```
import urllib
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addHeaders = [('User-agent', 'chrome')]

term = "vz"
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=nyse%3A"+term
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
search = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'e'})
searchtext = str(search)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(searchtext)
search2 = soup1.find('div', attrs = {'style':'margin-top:5px'})
searchtext2 = str(search2)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(searchtext2)
soup2 = soup2.span
data = soup2.findAll(text=True)
var1, var2, var3, var4 = data
```

With this, if you call any of the four variables, it'll give you the corresponding value from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant storing them all in seperate python variables, you could try:

```
data = soup2.findAll(text=True) #mind the not casting it to a string
(var1, var2, var3, var4) = data
```

And you'd have all your data in the variables var1, var2, var3 and var4. This would only work if you know the size of your array up front though.

Comment: That brought up the following error:                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samikhalifeh/Desktop/untitled.py", line 23, in <module>
    var1, var2, var3, var4 = data 
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: That is because `data` is not the list with 4 values, it is the entire html

Comment: edited my answer (pretty much also what Tim said :-))

Comment: I don't follow.  What entire html? Aren't those values stored in 'data'?

Comment: soup2.findAll(text=True) should return a list. but you use str(soup2.findAll(text=True)) which makes a string representation of that list. Then you use BeautifulSoup(data) to make that string representation of a list into an html (the html shown as your output). Try print soup2.findAll(text=True) to see the difference (this will give the same output as the string representation though).

Comment: That's what it was. I had to remove the BeautifulSoup and the string conversion.

Comment: Awesome, glad to be of help and thanks for letting me know it worked for you!